# Custom layout renderer 'not found' when using newer version of NLog

Tags: .net, versioning, nlog

I've created a custom NLog extension, which makes use of **NLog 3.1**. It contains, amongst other things, a layout renderer "iis-sitename", for retrieving the site name of IIS websites.

I've added the extension to the NLog configuration file of a .NET web service.

```
<extensions>
    <add assemblyFile="NLog.Extensions.dll"/>
</extensions>
```

The web service can use the layout renderer from the extension just fine, as long as it also uses **NLog 3.1**. But when I upgrade NLog in the web service to **3.2**, I get an error.

> Layout Renderer cannot be found: 'iis-sitename'.

I'm assuming this has something to do with a version conflict, as only the NLog **version** has changed. The code in both the extension and the web service have remained unaltered.

Is there a way this can be resolved without upgrading the extension to NLog 3.2 and keep using 3.2 for the web service?

Note: I can't upgrade NLog in the extension to 3.2 (yet), because other applications/services which also make use of the extension, are currently still using NLog 3.1.

In short, how can I set up an NLog extension DLL so it can be used by projects using either NLog 3.1 or 3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can direct your app to use the newer version of the assembly by putting assembly binding information in your app's configuration file as follows.

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.1.0" newVersion="3.2.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

More on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx).